# For what values of $a$ will $y=ax$ be a tangent to $x^2+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, tangent-line

For what values of $a$ will $y=ax$ be a tangent to $x^2+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$

I tried to solve this question by differentiating and making it equal to $0$ and solving for $x$ and i got $-10$ as an answer but when i graph the equation, it doesn't touch the circle. I don't know where i gone wrong. Can anyone help me with this question.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a circle, it should be $x^2 + y^2 + \cdots$ instead of $x^3$.

Comment: I know, but if you make everything equal to y and sketch it, it will come out as a circle with two halves.

Comment: Did you find the center and radius? Sketch the two tangent lines from the origin $(0,0)$ to the circle and draw the radii from the center of the circle to the two points of tangency. You should have two right triangles, each the reflection of the other. Can you figure out the slope of the two hypotenuses? That will give you your answers.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWaylandBales. but i didn't get what you mean. can you sketch that so i understand it better. Thanks.

Comment: @John: Are you sure that $x^{\color{red}{3}}+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$? This is [not a circle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2By%5E2%2B20x-10y%2B100%3D0). If you mean that $x^{\color{red}{2}}+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$, then this represents a circle, and it is correct that one of the $x$ coordinates of the tangent points is $-10$. (if you need more, I'll write an answer with a sketch.)

Comment: sorry about that. it was x^2

Answer (score 5):

Since $x^2+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$ can be written as
$$(x+10)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2,$$
we know that the center of the circle is $(-10,5)$ with radius $5$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Hence, it is easy to see that $a=\color{red}{0}$ is a solution where $(-10,0)$ is the tangent point.

Also, noting that $\tan\alpha=5/10=1/2$, we have
$$a=\tan\theta=\tan(\pi-2\alpha)=-\tan(2\alpha)=-\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}=\color{red}{-\frac 43}.$$

Comment: What tool did you use to draw the figure?

Comment: @PratyushYadav: I used [Adobe Illustrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator).

Answer (score 1):

A purely algebraic alternative.

If the line $y=ax$ is tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2+20x-10y+100=0$, then they should only have 1 point in common.

Substitution of $y=ax$ into the equation of the circle gives you a quadratic equation in $x$ with parameter $a$. This equation has exactly 1 solution if the discriminant is 0, so:
$$x^2+(ax)^2+20x-10ax+100=0 \Leftrightarrow (1+a^2)x^2+(20-10a)x+100=0$$
The discriminant is $(20-10a)^2-400(1+a^2)$, so:
$$(20-10a)^2-400(1+a^2) = 0 \Leftrightarrow -100a(3a+4) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \color{blue}{a = 0} \vee \color{blue}{a = -\frac{4}{3}}$$
So we find the same as in the answer with the more geometric approach.